# Yahoo pipe returns Null

Tags: null, yahoo-pipes

[Someone else asked a similar question](https://developer.yahoo.com/forum/Pipes/Pipe-functions-in-editor-debugger-but-returns/1368543143479-fc0fcad7-f80d-4062-97c4-bf71c48b5647) about this and I tried the solution offered by hapdaniel but this didn't work for me.

What is it that would cause my Pipe to return Nulll but in the editor it is working?

Essentially my XML feeds is fetching a list of URL website addresses. I then filter this feed to strip out everything and only give me the domain name such as http://www.example.com

Here's my sample Pipe:
[image] and the results showing Null
[image]
Many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You renamed `item.description` to `Address` with the **Rename** operator, and then in the **Create RSS** operator you try to use `item.description`, which doesn't exist anymore.

If you simply drop the **Rename** operator from your pipe it should work.

Btw, instead setting Description, it will be better to set Title *and* Link. That way the pipe output will be clickable links.

Here's a similar pipe if it helps:

http://pipes.yahoo.com/pipes/pipe.info?_id=14ebb3f522a0d5acf6ae4afb0ce9eecc

Comment: You are a scholar and a gent Janos, thanks. SO should honestly introduce payments of which they take micro payments. That way, if I choose to pay you for your answer, I choose a suggested amount and SO gets their tidbit.

Comment: Awesome, glad you're happy :) And yeah, that's a brilliant idea for SO!